# JDBC ConnectionPool Sharing Between WebApps

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, ucp

I am trying to migrate an application from WebSphere to Tomcat. I use JDBC connection pool to create connections and all the webapps shared it. But since Tomcat doesn't support EAR files. I am deploying all the different webapps separately. The jar file that has connection sharing code, I have put it in the Tomcat/lib folder. And also the `ojdbc5.jar` and `ucp.jar` in the same folder.

First I tried with the old shared objects code. And it threw some funky errors like:

```
class oracle.jdbc.driver.$Proxy35 cannot access its superinterface oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollRsetStatement
```

or

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface oracle.jdbc.internal.ClientDataSupport is not visible from class loader
```

This is the line causing issues.

```
connection = dataSource.getConnection();
```

After that I made the code that every webapp has its own connection object (not very efficient). But somehow even then the errors show up. Can you please guide me on how to get rid of this issue. I might have been a bit vague, because the issue is a little tricky to explain. If you need more info please do let me know.

Comment: Did you move to a newer Java version at the same time?

Comment: No, its all in JDK1.8

Comment: My only concern is, these classes are in the two Oracle jars I provided, but then why isn't it finding it.

Comment: It is finding them, it just can't load them because of classloader conflicts. You're not accidentally including the library jars in your webapps too by accident, are you?

Comment: I have the two dependencies in the webapps with the scope "provided". That should do the trick, wouldn't it?

Comment: Well those dependencies should be completely unnecessary, unless you're directly using classes from `ojdbc5.jar` or `ucp.jar`, which you shouldn't be doing.

Comment: Okay. The code has some direct imports from ucp.jar and the jdbc.jar. If I do remove them, what do i do instead? This is a very old application that I am working on, written more than a decade ago.

Comment: Just wanted to add, I am using ucp and ojdbc.jar version 11.2.0.4. If that is of any use.